# How to set ordering of calendar events in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendar, vuetify.js

In Vuetify, I am using a calendar, and I want the ordering of the events to be A,B,C,D same as in array. However it is coming out to C,A,B,D.

https://codepen.io/sneaky666/pen/rNxdaOQ?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fcalendars%2F

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-sheet>
        <v-calendar
          v-model="value"
          :events="events"
          :event-more="false" 
        ></v-calendar>
      </v-sheet>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    events : [
      {name:"A",start:"2020-07-06",end:"2020-07-06",timed:false},
      {name:"B",start:"2020-07-06",end:"2020-07-06",timed:false},
      {name:"C",start:"2020-07-06",end:"2020-07-08",timed:false},
      {name:"D",start:"2020-07-06",end:"2020-07-06",timed:false}
    ],
    value : ''
  }),
  methods: {
  },
})
```

How can this be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could define an ordered start time, for each event, and then use the event slot to display only the name.

```
 computed: {
    orderedEvents(){
      return this.events.map((event, index)=>{
        event.start = event.start + " 00:0" + index
        return event
      })
    }
  },

<v-calendar
      v-model="value"
      :events="orderedEvents"
      :event-more="false">
         <template v-slot:event={event}>
             <span class="px-2"> {{event.name}}</span> 
         </template>
</v-calendar>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. well actually it works if the dates start from the same day. But I updated the example in codepen to make C start at an earlier day and it still stays at the top. The times are set like how your code would generate too.